# Fast location of items via attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to quickly go straight to an item via the attribute table in QGIS 2.0.1? E.g similar to in ArcMap when you have the table open and double click the record and it zooms to it? I have a layer of ~175 points and I need to check these against the aerial imagery in OpenLayers and possibly insert new points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just select your feature in the attribute table and press `Pan map to the selected rows` (or use the key shortcut `Ctrl+P`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS plugin Item Browser. It's ideal for browse record.